# DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Extension Class Serialization in WCF App

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, serialization, account-management

I have a class i created named EmployeeData that inherits from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.  It allows me to easily access AD attributes using .  But i am trying to now move it to a WCF web service.  Is there a way for me to serialize my Employee class even though UserPrincipal is not serializeable?  IE: just serialize certain properties or create a different architecture?  I am new to this process, so forgive me if this is a terrible question.

For WCF, is there a way i can use the DataMember on only certain properties making it so the UserPrincipal class does not need to be serializeable?

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

<DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")>
<DirectoryObjectClass("Person")>
Public Class EmployeeData
    Inherits UserPrincipal

    Private _dataAccess As New DataAccess()

    Public Sub New(ByVal context As PrincipalContext)
        MyBase.New(context)
    End Sub

    <DirectoryProperty("samAccountName")>
    Public ReadOnly Property Username() As String
        Get
            Return SamAccountName
        End Get
    End Property

    <DirectoryProperty("givenName")>
    Public ReadOnly Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return GivenName
        End Get
    End Property

    <DirectoryProperty("sn")>
    Public ReadOnly Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return Surname
        End Get
    End Property

    <DirectoryProperty("mail")>
    Public ReadOnly Property Email() As String
        Get
            Return EmailAddress
        End Get
    End Property

    <DirectoryProperty("employeeNumber")>
    Public ReadOnly Property EEID As String
        Get
            If ExtensionGet("employeeNumber").Length <> 1 Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                Return ExtensionGet("employeeNumber")(0).ToString
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    <DirectoryProperty("department")>
    Public ReadOnly Property Dept As String
        Get
            If ExtensionGet("department").Length <> 1 Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                Return ExtensionGet("department")(0).ToString
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    <DirectoryProperty("division")>
    Public ReadOnly Property Division As String
        Get
            If ExtensionGet("division").Length <> 1 Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                Return ExtensionGet("division")(0).ToString
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    '<DirectoryProperty("title")>
    Public ReadOnly Property JobTitle As String
        Get
            If EEID IsNot Nothing Then
                Return _dataAccess.GetJobTitle(EEID)
            Else
                If ExtensionGet("title").Length <> 1 Then
                    Return "No AD Title"
                Else
                    Return ExtensionGet("title")(0).ToString
                End If
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    '<DirectoryProperty("manager")>
    Public ReadOnly Property ADManager As String
        Get
            If ExtensionGet("manager").Length <> 1 Then
                Return "No manager populated in AD"
            Else
                Dim m As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, ExtensionGet("manager")(0).ToString)
                If m IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return m.GivenName & " " & m.Surname
                Else
                    Return "Error"
                End If
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    <DirectoryProperty("telephoneNumber")>
    Public ReadOnly Property PhoneNumber As String
        Get
            If ExtensionGet("telephoneNumber").Length <> 1 Then
                Return "No Phone Number populated in AD"
            Else
                Return ExtensionGet("telephoneNumber")(0).ToString
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property HireDate As String
        Get
            Dim r
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(EEID) Then Return Nothing
            r = _dataAccess.GetHireDate(EEID)
            If IsNothing(r) Then Return Nothing

           Return r.ToShortDateString
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property YearsOfService As String
        Get
            If IsNothing(HireDate) Then Return Nothing

            Dim dateStart = Date.Parse(HireDate)

            If dateStart.ToShortDateString = "01/01/0001" Then Return Nothing

            'todo format yos string
            If HireDate >= Date.Now Then Return "Starting employement on " & HireDate

            Dim span As TimeSpan
            Dim length As Date

            Try
                span = Date.Now.AddDays(-1) - dateStart
                length = Date.MinValue + span
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return "Not Available"
            End Try

            'note: minValue is 1/1/1 so we have to subtract
            Dim years As Integer = length.Year - 1
            Dim months As Integer = length.Month - 1
            Dim days As Integer = length.Day - 1

            Return years & IIf(years <> 1, " years, ", " year, ") &
                   months & IIf(months <> 1, " months, ", " month, ") &
                   days & IIf(days <> 1, " days ", " day")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Supervisor As String
        Get
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(EEID) Then Return Nothing

            Dim supervisorId As String = _dataAccess.GetSupervisor(EEID)

            If supervisorId Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

            Return _dataAccess.GetADProperty("employeeNumber", supervisorId, "givenName") & " " & _dataAccess.GetADProperty("employeeNumber", supervisorId, "sn")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SupervisorUsername As String
        Get
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(EEID) Then Return Nothing

            Dim supervisorId As String = _dataAccess.GetSupervisor(EEID)

            If supervisorId Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

            Return _dataAccess.GetADProperty("employeeNumber", supervisorId, "samAccountName")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SupervisorEmail As String
        Get
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(EEID) Then Return Nothing

            Dim supervisorId As String = _dataAccess.GetSupervisor(EEID)

            If supervisorId Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

            Return _dataAccess.GetADProperty("employeeNumber", supervisorId, "mail")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Groups As IEnumerable
        Get
            Return _dataAccess.GetAdGroups(SamAccountName)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Shadows Function FindByIdentity(context As PrincipalContext, identityType As IdentityType,
                                                  identityValue As String) As EmployeeData
        Return DirectCast(FindByIdentityWithType(context, GetType(EmployeeData), identityType, identityValue), EmployeeData)
    End Function

    Public Shared Shadows Function FindByIdentity(context As PrincipalContext, identityValue As String) As EmployeeData
        Return DirectCast(FindByIdentityWithType(context, GetType(EmployeeData), identityValue), EmployeeData)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.AppendLine("Name: " & FirstName & " " & LastName & "<br/>")
        sb.AppendLine("EEID: " & EEID & "<br/>")
        sb.AppendLine("Email: " & Email & "<br/>")
        sb.AppendLine("Phone: " & PhoneNumber & "<br/>")
        'sb.AppendLine("Supervisor Email: " & SupervisorEmail & "<br/>")
        'sb.AppendLine("Username: " & Username & "<br/>")
        'sb.AppendLine("Dept: " & Dept & "<br/>")
        'sb.AppendLine("Division: " & Division & "<br/>")
        'sb.AppendLine("Job Title: " & JobTitle & "<br/>")
        'sb.AppendLine("Active Directory Manager: " & ADManager & "<br/>")
        sb.AppendLine()
        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You're probably better off to write a class to contain the data to send over the wire.   note that serialization won't work with readonly properties.   You need a getter and a setter.  Additionally (this is an IMO) some of your properties should be methods as they contain quite a bit of logic.

Comment: Thanks That's exactly what I did. Also good call on the properties as well. I ended up just taking the inheritance out of my class and use methods to grab the attributes I needed instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per advise, I stopped inheriting UserPrincipal and gendered methods to get the attributes validating them on the way in. Then I was able to use the data contract attribute and data method to serialize the class with no issues.